# Duplicating site in the same server

Tags: php

I am newbie in web "programming"/designing and I want to ask you a question. I hope to find a solution here, because I see many experienced web developers in this site.

Situation :

There are a website files in the server in /public_html/
there is index.html

I want to translate the website doing duplication of the website, so translated site files I put in /public_html/**en/**

Question: When i type in www.mysite.com**/en**, automaticly I am getting www.mysite.com**/en/en/** site which is blank. Why?

Why I can not access www.mysite.com**/en/index.html ?**

If I try to type in ...com**/en/**images/map.jpg I can acces the image easily.

I hope you will understand. Thank you

Comment: you have *something* redirecting `/en` to `/en/en`

Comment: are you using some kind of `CMS` or just simple html page?

Comment: Since it is not my website and I dont have contacts with man, who programmed the site, I cant really tell much. It is using cms, but i dont even know what it is called, sure thing it is written with jquery. Maybe I could give an access to the server to community's trusted webdeveloper, or post source code of index here.

Comment: Typing www.mysite.com/en/index.html is not working. And Dagon1, I dont think so, because I tried to rename /en/ to something else, and still url/smthelse/ didnt work.

Comment: There is also cfg.php and I think built cms file redaktorius.php (redactor in english) and  somehow they are all associated with one or another, but I cant find the variable that defines redirecting to url/x/x